# How do I avoid multiple apk install promps on an Android programmatic install?

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

Our Android applications automatically check for updates every 5 minutes in the background and downloads the latest .apk file from our downloads server.

It then fires off an install using the below method:

```
public static void installDownloadedApplication(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard, Constants.APPLICATION_CODE+".apk");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

This prompts the end-user (using the standard Android OS application install prompt) to install or cancel the application apk.

If only one of our applications are in need of an update, the Android install prompt appears only once no matter how many times the above code in that one application runs.

The problem we are having is that if the user leaves his Android device for a long while and MULTIPLE of his applications need to auto update at the same time, this code is run every 5 minutes for each application, but now multiple Android install prompts appear for the second application that tries to install.

Example 1: only application X gets an update, the user leaves it for 15 mins, and only one install prompt for application X appears.

Example 2: both application X and Y get an update, the user leaves it for 15 mins, and 1 install prompts appear for application X but 3 install prompts appear for application Y

Any ideas what could be causing the problem in example 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working properly without the duplicates by having our background service call a custom activity:

```
public static void installDownloadedApplication(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, InstallActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then our custom activity does what the background service used to do:

```
/**
 * We use an activity to kick off the installer activity in order to avoid issues that arise when kicking off the apk installer from a background services
 * for multiple applications at the same time.
 * */
public class InstallActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard, Constants.APPLICATION_CODE+".apk");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server tells you the latest APK. Compare this to the one in your download area. If you have already downloaded the latest version, you don't need to download it again.

Also, when you start the install via `Intent`, remember that by writing the version ID and date/time into a shared preferences. Don't try to install the same version again until X hours/days have passed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately our server only tells us that the application is outdated. The app then responds by downloading the static named apk file from the download area and installing it. It doesn't download it again if the file already exists on the device, but it does try and install it again each time. This is where the problem is.

Comment: Well, you probably shouldnt ask the user to install it every 5 minutes. Once per day should be enough. I can't suggest anything else. sorry.

Comment: I have figured out more info on this and updated the original question slightly